# make rails link as bootstrap button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have anchor links in rails like this.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

I want to have them as a button and I want to use bootstrap button.

Here's how I am trying to achieve it.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) :class => "btn" %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', products_path :class => "btn"%>
</div>
```

But this is not working for some reason.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot the comma after the path:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :class => "btn" %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :class => "btn"%>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn! Thank god I posted here early or else I would've wasted lot of time.

Comment: Could be my circumstances, but I had to add btn-primary.  So <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651691/4695439 for a more sensible answer. The div classes here are pointless

Answer (score 3):

Other than the comma is missing, it would be better to remove or modify the class attribute in the div tag to something more sensible it as this would create an unnecessary duplicate of buttons inside one another. It should look something like this:

`<div>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :class => "btn btn-primary" %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :class => "btn"%>
</div>`